# null value in asp.net page.items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with behind C# code.
I add a page Item in main page. then I used some web user control.
In one of them, when I use this Item in page_load. it has correct value, but when I use it in another private function in same web control, it has null value!
then I prefered to use a public string and set the value of that Item in it. but not working too.

```
public string ReqID0;
string Status0 { get; set; }
string Status = "";

string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlc4;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        ReqID0 = Page.Items["ReqID"].ToString();
        ReqIDLbl.Text = ReqID0;
...
```

second function (method) is:

```
    private void Change_Status(string newStatus)
    {

        //ReqID0=Page.Items["ReqID"].ToString();

        sqlc4 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Request SET Status=@newStatus WHERE ID=@ReqID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newStatus", newStatus);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", ReqID0);


        cmd.Connection = sqlc4;
        sqlc4.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlc4.Close();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page.Item refreshes with each post back and you have to add it every time your  page refreshes ,,and as per your code here in  `Page_Load` event

```
 if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        ReqID0 = Page.Items["ReqID"].ToString();
        ReqIDLbl.Text = ReqID0;
```

--Assigning of value is getting bypassed when your page does a post back and you get Null value in your `Change_Status` method. Try using `Viewstate` Instead.

Use the Items property to store objects with the same lifetime as the page request. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Update**: try using `ViewState`.

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
      ViewState["ReqID"]= ReqIDLbl.Text;
        //ReqID0 = Page.Items["ReqID"].ToString();
       //ReqIDLbl.Text = ReqID0;



private void Change_Status(string newStatus)
    {

        //ReqID0=ViewState["ReqID"].ToString();
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user3051479 Didn't get what you want to tell ,Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The global variables are created / intialized between postback in asp.net and they do not retain the values between postback as http is stateless protocol, you need to use ViewState for that.

```
public string ReqID0;
string Status0 { get; set; }
string Status = "";

string ConnectionString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection sqlc4;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    ReqIDLbl.Text = ReqID0;
    ReqID0 = ViewState["ReqID0"].ToString();//ViewState
  /*In case if the above code doesn't work use 
   ReqIDLbl.Text =  ViewState["ReqID0"].ToString();*/
  ------
 }
```

//Second Function

```
   private void Change_Status(string newStatus)
{

    ReqID0=ViewState["ReqID0"].ToString();

    sqlc4 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Request SET Status=@newStatus WHERE ID=@ReqID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newStatus", newStatus);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", ReqID0);


    cmd.Connection = sqlc4;
    sqlc4.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlc4.Close();       
  }
```

Hope This might give you the answer

Comment: not working! error on :ViewState["ReqID0"].ToString();//ViewState